# Function assigning to ng-model in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I want to integrate a slider into my website. I use http://darul75.github.io/ng-slider/ for that. However I do not want to use hardcoded starting points and end points for my slider. Neither do I want a hard coded default value such as

```
  $scope.value = 1000000;
  $scope.options={
      from :10,
      to : 100,
      step : 1,
      dimension : " $"
  }
```

and in my view

```
<input ng-model="value"  type="text" id="mySlider1" slider options="options" />
```

Instead I prefer using a function for both options.from/options.to as well as for value.

The function for value for example should be looks something like:

```
function(){
          var arrayToPush=[];
          for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              arrayToPush.push($scope.data[i].hops[0].total_price.EUR)
          }
          return arrayToPush.max();
      };
```

Note that the data comes from a standard HTTP request and returns an array
Similarly should the functions for `from`and `to`look like. Firstly, how can I assign a function to ng-model and secondly how to I assign a function to `from`?

Hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. I defined an additional function:

```
$scope.maxValue=(function(){
          var arrayToPush=[];
          for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
              arrayToPush.push($scope.data[i].hops[0].total_price.EUR)
          }
          return arrayToPush.length>0 ? Math.round(Math.max.apply( Math, arrayToPush)) : 5000;
      })($scope.data);
```

and assigned this to `value`and to `to`. However, the wrong part was my function to get the maximum value of an array and the second to assign a function and not the value only.